# How to make Playwright not to raise exceptions when the browser is closed

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a interface which has a button that closes the playwright context and browser, but when i close it, a lot of exceptions (because the playwright browser and context were closed during some actions) are raised and i couldn't ignore them with try/except. This is a problem because the exceptions always shutdown the interface window. Here is a sample of code:

```
def close_playwright():
    context.close()
    browser.close()

playwright = sync_playwright().start() 
browser = playwright.webkit.launch()
context = self.browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=False)
page = context.new_page()
page.goto("https://example.com")
# do something 
# sometime close_playwright() is called and the exceptions are raised
```

Comment: Actually there is no need to close Context, closing Browser is enough.

Comment: By the way, in some cases you can run Playwright API via `with` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was i was trying to close the context before closing the page first, and that was the thing which raises unhandleable exceptions. The solution is replacing the `close_playwright()` function with this:

```
def close_playwright():

    page.close()
    context.close()
    browser.close()
    playwright.dispose()
```